# How to use Vaadin's CustomLayout with custom style?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have an HTML file, which serves as a template for my Vaadin view.

This HTML file uses several styles from a custom CSS file, let's call it `custom.css`.

Imagine I create a `CustomLayout` instance `a` from that file. I want `a` to use styles from `custom.css` only and ignore the theme styles.

How can I do that?

Notes:

1. I know that I can create my own themes etc., but in practice this is not useful since styling the theme via a myriad of styles is too cumbersome. 
   Instead, I want that the UI designer creates the view template in Dreamweaver (or similar tool) and then I integrate that view into the Vaadin application.
2. I know about `CustomLayout.addStyleName(...)`, but I don't want to add the styles manually.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `@com.vaadin.annotations.StyleSheet` annotation. It makes possible to load css files from classpath or external urls.